# Как увеличить значение поля на 1 через SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

c условием путем update и в поля не должно попасть число больше 14

```
        ....
elif message.text == "Next Page ➡":
        ...
        conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
        c = conn.cursor()
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        sql = "insert into tmp (user_id, page) values (:user_id, :page) "
        data = {}
        data["user_id"] = user_id
        data['page'] = 1
        c.execute(sql, data)

        data = {}
        data["user_id"] = message.from_user.id
        data['page'] + 1                 ### <<------------- ??
        c.execute(sql, data)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
update tmp set page=page+1 where user_id=1;
```