# SQL "=+" работает не корректно

Tags: python, sqlite3

```
if message.text == "Price" and req_db[str(message.from_user.id)] <= 48:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Write the COIN symbol and CURRENCY symbol. Example: BTC USD')
    cur.execute("UPDATE users SET requests =+ 1 ")
    con.commit()
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, currency)
```

По сути оно должно добавлять 1 к указаному значению. Код это делает, но только 1 раз. После последующих попыток 1 к 1 не прибавляется

Comment: То, что вы написали, эквивалентно `requests = +1`, то есть вы просто записываете единицу в поле requests, никакого прибавления тут нет

Comment: @andreymal читал документацию, думал, что написал правильно. Не могли бы вы кинуть правильный пример?

Comment: Где в документации вы это читали?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-equals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Во-первых, это вообще не sqlite3, а во-вторых, там написано не то, что написали вы

Comment: @andreymal понял, моя ошибка. Что насчёт правильного решения? И есть ли вообще такая возможность сделать в sqlite3

Comment: А в целом вопрос про прибавление в sqlite3 уже когда-то был на этом сайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518413

Comment: @andreymal окей, благодарю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как увеличить значение поля на 1 через SQLite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518413/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-1-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-sqlite)